# Taylor series on complex analysis

Tags: complex-numbers

Suppose that, I have $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (z^n)/n$.

Now clearly for the open disk $|z|<1$, above series converges. But if I consider $|z|=1$, then clearly for $z=1$, above series diverges. How do I prove that the series converges for all $z$ such that $|z|=1$ except for $z=1$. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result can be proven by application of Dirichlet's test for series:

> If $\{a_n\}_{n\in \Bbb N}$ is a sequence of complex numbers and $\{b_n\}_{n\in \Bbb N}$ is a sequence of real numbers such that $b_n$ decreases to $0$ and the sequence of partial sums of $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty a_n$ is bounded, then $\sum\limits_{n= 1}^\infty a_nb_n$ converges.

If $|z| = 1$ and $z \neq 1$, we may write $z = e^{i\theta}$ where $\theta$ is not an integer multiple of $2\pi$. Take $a_n = z^n = e^{in\theta}$ and $b_n = 1/n$. Then $b_n$ decreases to $0$. For each $N$,

$$\sum_{n = 1}^N a_n = \frac{e^{i(N+1)\theta} - e^{i\theta}}{e^{i\theta} - 1} = \frac{e^{i(N + 1/2)\theta} - e^{i\theta/2}}{e^{i\theta/2} - e^{-i\theta/2}}= \frac{1}{2i\sin(\theta/2)}(e^{i(N+1/2)\theta} - e^{i\theta/2}).$$

(Note: $\sin(\theta/2) \neq 0$ because $\theta/2$ is not an integer multiple of $\pi$) Since $|e^{i(N+1/2)\theta} - e^{i\theta/2}| \le 2$ it follows that

$$\left|\sum_{n = 1}^N a_n\right| \le \frac{1}{|\sin(\theta/2)|}.$$

So the sequence of partial sums of $\sum\limits_{n= 1}^\infty a_n$ is bounded. Hence, by Dirichlet's test, the series $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty z^n/n$ converges.

Comment: Now,I found it can be done by picard's theorem also.